# How to use scroll to view within expansion panel

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, scrolltop

Context:
I am trying to achieve this --> https://hhk6r.csb.app/

Mock:

[image]

**Problem:**

Scroll to view on the div element does not scroll to the start of the expansion panel.

[image]

Docs:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

I have tried using the block:'start' option provided in the docs, not able to figure out where am i going wrong any suggestions would be helpful.

I have created codesandbox to replicate the issue, this is what I have tried till now.

https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-issue-kyoxf

Comment: Tried using scroll-margin-top on the parent(div)) of all expansion panel. https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-issue-forked-4q91s?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Oh my bad yeah. This one is used in case of some vanilla behavior with an anchor like `href="div#my-section-1"`. Here, it looks like you have some other behavior, try to replicate some scroll down with JS or switching to href anchor could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

On top of your current work, you could properly offset the whole thing with

```css
scroll-margin-top: 2rem;
```

All kudos go to Josh Comeau and his nice tweet that can be found here: https://twitter.com/joshwcomeau/status/1332015868725891076?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack is to properly offset the margin top using scroll-margin-top